# How do I iterate through the rows of a column, group them, write a sequential value in a different column, then move to next?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I currently have an Excel spreadsheet where column B has a value that I want to identify as a group and then write that group number in column C.  Column B is presorted A-Z.  Here's a sample where column A is the record number, column B is text info to sort through, and column C is the sequential group created and written by this formula or sub.  There are about 100,000 rows to iterate through.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | ARNOLD | 1 |
| 7 | ARNOLD | 1 |
| 8 | ARNOLD | 1 |
| 9 | ARNOLD | 1 |
| 16 | DEWY | 2 |
| 17 | DEWY | 2 |
| 18 | DEWY | 2 |
| 14 | FOX | 3 |
| 15 | FOX | 3 |
| 19 | JAMIE | 4 |
| 20 | JAMIE | 4 |

Thanks for your help - Jack

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried so far, moreover it would help if you add your expected output as well. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: First, you want to use the internal sort method on column B. Then, you can simply iterate through and add the incrementing column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread originally and I now see that your data is presorted. So to simply label the entries, the following should work for you:

```
Range("B:B").Select
Dim curval As Long
curval = 1
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo -1
        Exit Do
    End If
    Range("C" & Selection.Row) = curval
    curval = curval + 1
Loop
```

First, we select the column and create our index variable. Then, we loop through `Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select`. This will highlight the full set with the first entry being the selected point. Having that, we can set our column C, which would be the first row to the current index and increase the index for the next set.

Using this feature (`Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select`) will raise an error upon completion. So, we preceed that with `On Error Resume Next` and follow it up by checking for the error. If it exists, we exit the loop and clear the error (`On Error Goto -1`).

Edit: The following should solve your issue of populating ALL as opposed to just the first entry:

```
Public Sub test()
Range("B:B").Select
Dim curval As Long, prev_row As Long
curval = 1
prev_row = 2
On Error Resume Next
Set first_sel = Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell)
first_sel.Select
Do
    Set second_sel = Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell)
    second_sel.Select
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo -1
        Exit Do
    End If
    Range("C" & first_sel.Row & ":" & "C" & second_sel.Row - 1) = curval
    Set first_sel = second_sel
    curval = curval + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution correctly populates the numbered groupings I asked for in the first occurrences of the groups.  I added an additional piece of code I stumbled across that will fill in the values for column C.

Comment: See the added entry.

Comment: Great work and so very close.  It identifies and populates all the groupings except for the final group.  I am happy to use this and add a dummy row at the bottom.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on your input data provided in the original post, this works for me including the final group. Arnold, Dewy, Fox, Jamie are labeled 1, 2, 3, 4, respectively. So I'm not sure. If necessary you could add a dummy row as you suggested but do it via VBA and also clear it and the end of the sub routine. This would make it transparent. But without seeing it fail myself, I don't know the solution.

Comment: Great idea adding the dummy row in VBA and then removing it.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: Sure, good luck!